# Select a large volume of data with like SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with ID column

ID column is like this : IDxxxxyyy
x will be 0 to 9

I have to select row with ID like ID0xxx% to ID3xxx%, there will be around 4000 ID with % wildcard from ID0000% to ID3999%.

It is like combining LIKE with IN

```
Select * from TABLE where ID in (ID0000%,ID0001%,...,ID3999%)
```

I cannot figure out how to select with this condition.

If you have any idea, please help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not clear! What did you try? Search for LIKE operator!

Comment: I need to select like this : Select * from TABLE where ID in (ID0000%,ID0001%,...,ID3999%) . There are 4000 IDxxxx in the list with % wildcard.

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan you already wrote that and it's not clear. There's no such syntax. If you want to select everything between `ID0` and `ID3` just use LIKE and OR,eg `ID LIKE 'ID0%' OR ID LIKE 'ID1%'...`. 4K rows is no data at all anyway, and a "smart" database key is a bad design choice. If the first digit means something, it should be a separate field, probably covered by an index. This would allow you to write eg `WHERE CategoryID IN (0,1,2,3)` or `CategoryID<=3`

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan I strongly advice you to follow Gareth's advice. Pattern matching is slow and can't really take advantage of indexes except for simple prefix searches. In other cases, it has to scan the entire table for matches. It may run adequately with just 4K rows (these can easily fit in the CPUs cache after all) but will use a lot of IO and CPU for even small amounts of data

Comment: It seems to me that, your design is not a good approach. You should take @Gareth's advice for the second solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching with `LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-by-using-like). e.g.

```
WHERE ID LIKE 'ID[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Will match an string that:

1. Starts with ID (`ID`)
2. Then has a third character that is a number between 0 and 3 [0-3]
3. Then has 3 further numbers (`[0-9][0-9][0-9]`)

This is not likely to perform well at all. If it is not too late to alter your table design, I would separate out the components of your `Identifier` and store them separately, then use a computed column to store your full id e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
        NumericID INT NOT NULL,
        YYY CHAR(3) NOT NULL, -- Or whatever type makes up yyy in your ID
        FullID AS CONCAT('ID', FORMAT(NumericID, '0000'), YYY),
    CONSTRAINT PK_T__NumericID_YYY PRIMARY KEY (NumericID, YYY)
);
```

Then your query is a simple as:

```
SELECT  FullID
FROM    T
WHERE   NumericID >= 0 
AND     NumericID < 4000;
```

This is significantly easier to read and write, and will be significantly faster too.

Comment: I prefer the second solution for better design, anyway +1.

Comment: @Phong SO do not promote comment like +1, thank you, upvoted, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This should do that, it will get all the IDs that start with IDx, with x that goes form 0 to 4

```
Select * from TABLE where ID LIKE 'ID[0-4]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
Select * from TABLE where id like 'ID[0-3][0-9]%[a-zA-Z]';
```